Some weird bijection from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
It is very simple that $f_k(t)= t^{2k+1}$, where $k \in  \mathbb{N}$, is a bijection between $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
This example is very normal. Can anyone give a more special function which can be explicitly expressed (which means that it can be expressed by a formula), and this function is not a piecewise function and is not a polynomial function.
Thanks in advance.
Can anyone give me an answer why this question is closed? And who did it? I don't think this is a meaningness question.

$f(t)=\sinh t$.

To give an additional example to complement @hunter's great and beautiful candidate, one I could think of is
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}&\to\mathbb{R}, \\ x &\mapsto x+\mathrm{e}^x
\end{align*}
$$
with inverse
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}&\to\mathbb{R}, \\ x &\mapsto x-W(\mathrm{e}^x).
\end{align*}
$$
The upshot: This is a bijection. The slight beauty mistake: Its inverse is not an elementary function (the $W$ stands for the Lambert W function, where the defining property states $a=be^b \iff b=W(a)$; note that $W$ actually comes with multiple branches ... I'll let you figure out the choice of branch, depending on your input value).
As a graph ($x \mapsto x+\mathrm{e}^x$ drawn in red, and its inverse in black):
$x \mapsto x+\mathrm{e}^x$ (in red) and its inverse (in black)" />
To follow @hunter's reasoning for a monotonically increasing bijection, you may have a look at $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x + \arctan(x)$.

A nice example to have in your head for questions like this is $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$. This function is strictly increasing since its derivative has only isolated zeroes, but it doesn't increase any faster than $y=x$ on average.
